# What $X=Y$ in distribution means?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P) $ a probability space.

1) What $X=Y$ in distribution means ? Is it that $$\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}=\mathbb P\{Y\leq x\}$$
for all $x\in \Omega $ ?

2) If $(\tilde\Omega ,\tilde{\mathcal F},\mathbb Q)$ an other probability space. Let $X:\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ and $Y:\tilde\Omega \to \mathbb R$ two r.v. Would $X=Y$ would have sense ? If not, what would mean $$\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}=\mathbb Q\{Y\leq x\} \ \ ?$$

Comment: Technically, it would mean $P\{X \in A\} = P\{Y \in A\}$ for every measurable set $A$ in the target sigma algebra. But in your case the target sigma algebra is the set of reals equipped with the Borel sigma algebra. Since sets of the form $(\infty,x]$ generate this Borel sigma algebra, it is sufficient to check the equality I wrote for sets of this type.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ in the target sigma algebra" ? wouldn't it be $X^{-1}(A)$ and $Y^{-1}(A)$ in the target sigma algebra ? Because as written $A\subset \mathbb R$...

Comment: Never use bold Q for anything besides the rationals

Comment: That would be $A \in B(\mathbb{R})$ in your case. So the sigma algebra generated by the open sets of the space where your random variables are taking values.

Comment: @whycantihavealongername: This is commonly used for measure of probability...

Answer (score 1):

1. It means that $P(X\le x)=P(Y\le x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$, not all $x\in \Omega$. In this context, $x$ is a real number, whereas elements of $\Omega$ are not.
2. The equality $X=Y$ only makes sense in distribution, in which case it means exactly what you wrote (for all $x\in \mathbb R$). This is sometimes written as $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$.